# Request for member 'row' in something not a structure or union

Tags: uitableview

this is my first time here!

I'm getting that error when configuring an UITableViewCell.

This is my Cell:

```
@interface CellView : UITableViewCell {
    IBOutlet UILabel *nombre;
    IBOutlet UILabel *estado;
}

-(void)setName:(NSString *) name;
```

And this is the method that executes for every row:

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSInteger *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellView";

    CellView *cell = (CellView *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil){
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellView" owner:nil options:nil];
        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell = (CellView *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    [cell setName:[latitudes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;    
}
```

latitudes is a NSMutableArray

I've tried also with cell.nombre.text=[latitudes objetcAtIndex:indexPath.row]; but still returns the same error.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method signature seems to be wrong:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSInteger *)indexPath
```

It should be (note the type of the `indexPath` parameter):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Ok, done! Well, this is the first time I am building a TableView. Now I'm wondering why it's not constructing it... Do I have to call the method any time? I'm inicialitating the NSMuteArray in application:didFinnisLaunchingWithMethod. Added a NSLog in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection but it's never called! :S Thanks again!

Comment: You do not have to call the methods directly. The table view will call the methods if you have set the datasource and delegate properly. If it is the first time you are building a table view, check out [this tutorial](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/3392-uitableviews-tutorial-part-1-a.html)